# expected value, vat containing millions of marbles

Tags: probability

A vat contains millions of marbles. 20% of them have the number “6” carved on them, and the rest have the number “17” carved on them.  Find the expected value.

My thinking:

E(x)= 17*.8 + 6*.2 = 14.8

P.S.  I am confused by the "millions."  Should I be using an integral?  However, bc this is discrete random variable I though not.  Please advise.

Comment: Your method is fine.  Well, you don't actually say what you want the expected value of.  I am assuming you meant "expected value of a random draw".

Comment: "*Find the expected value*"  The expected value *of what*?  What are we doing with this vat of marbles?  Pulling some out?  How many do we pull out?  Do we add the numbers that we pulled out?  Do we multiply them?  Do we ask our neighbor to say a random number?

Comment: here is the problem:

Comment: A vat contains millions of marbles. 20% of them have the number “6” carved on them, and the rest have the number “17” carved on them.
a) We draw a marble from the vat. Find the expected value.

Comment: Yes, the "*we draw a marble from the vat*" was missing from your original post.  We could just as easily have asked the question "*we draw ten marbles from the vat and add the numbers appearing on them*" and been tasked with finding the expected value of the sum.  For your problem, the "millions" bit is indeed irrelevant, this could just as easily been a problem about a bag with five marbles total, four of which had $17$ written on them and one of which with a $6$ written on it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 'millions' in this context simply means 'many'. To be honest, that is redundant information. You already have the answer. But just to be rigorous,

$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum x p(x). $$

And this is the same as your working.

Comment: thank you!  I am new to this type of work, so using formulas, trying to understand concepts... I read this is the same as "average?"

Comment: @rgentil32 There is a difference in nuance and semantics, expected value is more for random variables while average is more for data, but otherwise yes they are effectively the same root concept.

Comment: thanks JMoravitz